# How to convert a time string in a Google AppEngine db.TimeProperty?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore

As per question title, how to convert a Python `string` to a Google App Engine `db.TimeProperty`?

I tried to do:

```
obj.time = strptime("10:00", "%H:%M")
```

However I get the following error:

> BadValueError: Property time must be a time,  but was
>   time.struct_time(tm_year=1900, tm_mon=1,  tm_mday=1, tm_hour=10,
>   tm_min=0, tm_sec=0,  tm_wday=0, tm_yday=1, tm_isdst=-1)

Comment: You really really shouldn't be using the `db` library, it's been deprecated for years.

Comment: @DanielRoseman It applies to ndb as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with the (superseded) `db` docs, but from the [NDB Cheat Sheet](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1AefylbadN456_Z7BZOpZEXDq8cR8LYu7QgI7bt5V0Iw/mobilebasic) `db.TimeProperty()` corresponds directly to `ndb.TimeProperty()`. And from `ndb`'s [Date and Time Properties](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/entity-property-reference#Date_and_Time):

> Three property types are available for storing date- and time-related
>   values:
>
> - `DateProperty`
> - `TimeProperty`
> - `DateTimeProperty`
>
> These take values belonging to the corresponding classes (`date`,
>   `time`, `datetime`) of the standard Python `datetime` module. The most
>   general of the three is `DateTimeProperty`, which denotes both a
>   calendar date and a time of day; the others are occasionally useful
>   for special purposes requiring just a date (such as a date of birth)
>   or just a time (such as a meeting time). For technical reasons,
>   `DateProperty` and `TimeProperty` are subclasses of
>   `DateTimeProperty`, but you shouldn't depend on this inheritance
>   relationship (and note that it differs from the inheritance
>   relationships between the underlying classes defined by the `datetime`
>   module itself).

So I'd write it:

```
obj.time = datetime.datetime.strptime("10:00", "%H:%M").time()
```